# Graphql type included in interface not added to schema in graphene-django

Tags: interface, graphql, react-apollo, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have an interface type implemented by two concrete types

```
interface InterfaceType {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

 type Type1 implements InterfaceType {
    aField: String
}

 type Type2 implements InterfaceType {
    anotherField: String
}
```

Using graphene-django:

```
class InterfaceType(graphene.Interface):
    id = graphene.ID(required=True)
    name = graphene.String(required=True)

class Type1(graphene_django.types.DjangoObjectType):
    a_field = graphene.String(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        interfaces = (InterfaceType,)

class Type2(graphene_django.types.DjangoObjectType):
    another_field = graphene.String(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        interfaces = (InterfaceType,)
```

This works as long as some query or mutation uses `Type1` and `Type2` directly. But in my case they are only used indirectly, through `InterfaceType`.

The problem is when I try to request `aField` or `anotherField` through inline fragments:

```
query {
    interfaceQuery {
        id
        name
        ...on Type1 {
            aField
        }
        ...on Type2 {
            anotherField
        }
    }
```

Using react-apollo:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const interfaceQuery = gql`
    query {
        interfaceQuery {
            id
            name
            ... on Type1 {
                aField
            }
            ... on Type2 {
                anotherField
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

I get the error `"Unknown type "Type1". Perhaps you meant ..."`

It's like the types aren't added to the schema since they're not directly in use - but I still need them in order to query `aField` and `anotherField`.

Can you spot a mistake in the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `Type1` and `Type2` to your schema explicitly. Graphene needs that little bit of guidance from your side to know you want to add those types to your Schema.

```py
schema = graphene.Schema(
    query=Query,
    mutation=Mutation,
    types=[
        Type1,
        Type2,
    ]
)
```

This is also [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/interfaces/#interfaces) (though a bit easy to overlook I guess). When you look at the example code there is a line like this:

```py
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, types=[Human, Droid])
```

which therefore (as an aside) might be a nice example for why it might be better to not collapse some things into a single line even though you can w.r.t. line length.

Comment: Nice!!!!! Finally I found the proper way of including graphene types after hours of google search!